# pytest list fixture execution

Tags: python, pytest

For a given test, I'd like to find out the order of fixtures execution/fixture calls. This is sometimes hard to follow by debugging if the codebase is large and fixtures are defined in lots of different places. Is this possible to do? `pytest --fixtures -v` just lists all the fixtures called, but not the order of execution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the flag `--setup-plan`. From the documentation

> show what fixtures and tests would be executed but don't execute anything.

Running pytest with that flag show:

- the fixture used by each test
- the order of the setup and teardown of the fixtures
- the dependency of each fixture

More flags(like`--fixtures-per-test --setup-show`) that can help you find the required information can be found here https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#command-line-flags .